# Remove elements when satisfying certain condition

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a large list:

```
a=[[4,34,1], [5,87,2], [2,76,9],...]
```

I want to compare all pairs of sub-lists, such that if

```
a[i][0]>a[j][0] and a[i][1]>a[j][1]
```

then the sub-list `a[i]` should be removed.
How could I achieve this goal in Python 2.7?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly more idiomatic way of implementing @MisterMiyagi approach:

```
drop = set()
for i, j in itertools.combinations(range(len(a)), 2):
    # I would've used ``enumerate`` here as well, but it is
    # easier to see the filtering criteria with explicit 
    # indexing.
    if a[i][0] > a[j][0] and a[i][1] > a[j][1]:
        drop.add(i)

a = [value for idx, value in enumerate(a) if idx not in drop]
print(a)
```

How is it more idiomatic?

- Combinatorial iterator from `itertools` instead of a double forloop.
- No extra `0:` in slices.
- `enumerate` instead of explicit indexing to build the answer.

P.S. This is a O(N^2) solution so it might take a while for large inputs.

Comment: Good catch, thanks! I've updated the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you sort the list first (an `O(n log n)` operation), then you can identify
the items to keep (or reject) in one pass by comparing neighbors (an `O(n)`
operation). So for long lists this should be much faster than comparing all
pairs (an `O(n**2)` operation).

At the bottom of the post you'll find the code for `using_sort`:

```
In [22]: using_sort([[4,34,1], [5,87,2], [2,76,9]])
Out[22]: [[2, 76, 9], [4, 34, 1]]

In [23]: using_sort([[4, 34, 1], [5, 87, 2], [2, 76, 9], [4, 56, 12], [9, 34, 76]])
Out[23]: [[2, 76, 9], [4, 56, 12], [4, 34, 1], [9, 34, 76]]
```

---

We can compare that against a `O(n**2)` algorithm, `using_product`, based on [Sergei Lebedev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36085798/190597).

First, let's check that they give the same result:

```
import numpy as np
tests = [
    [[4, 34, 1], [5, 87, 2], [2, 76, 9], [4, 56, 12], [9, 34, 76]],
    [[87, 26, 37], [50, 37, 23], [70, 97, 19], [86, 91, 55], [57, 55, 68],
     [25, 35, 64], [82, 79, 66], [1, 30, 75], [16, 14, 71], [32, 89, 6]],
    np.random.randint(100, size=(10, 3)).tolist(),
    np.random.randint(100, size=(50, 3)).tolist(),
    np.random.randint(100, size=(100, 3)).tolist()]

assert all([sorted(using_product(test)) == sorted(using_sort(test)) 
            for test in tests])
```

---

Here is a benchmark showing `using_sort` is much faster than `using_product`. 
Since `using_sort` is `O(n log n)` while `using_product` is `O(n**2)`,
the speed advantage increases with the length of `a`.

```
In [17]: a = np.random.randint(100, size=(10**4, 3)).tolist()

In [20]: %timeit using_sort(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.44 ms per loop

In [21]: %timeit using_product(a)
1 loops, best of 3: 6.17 s per loop
```

---

I found visualizing the solution helpful. For each point in the result there is
a blue rectangular region emanating from it with the given point in the lower
left corner. This rectangular region depicts the set of points which can be
eliminated due to that point being in the result.

With `using_sort`, each time a point is found in the result, it keeps checking subsequent points in the sorted list against this point until it finds the next point in the result.

```
import itertools as IT
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
np.random.seed(2016)

def using_sort(a):
    if len(a) == 0: return []
    a = sorted(a, key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[1]))
    result = []
    pt = a[0]
    nextpt = pt
    for key, grp in IT.groupby(a, key=lambda x: x[0]):
        for item in grp:
            if not (item[0] > pt[0] and item[1] > pt[1]):
                result.append(item)
                nextpt = item
        pt = nextpt
    return result

def using_product(a):
    drop = set()
    for i, j in IT.product(range(len(a)), repeat=2):
        if (i != j 
            and i not in drop 
            and j not in drop
            and a[i][0] > a[j][0] 
            and a[i][1] > a[j][1]):
            drop.add(i)
    a = [value for idx, value in enumerate(a) if idx not in drop]
    return a

def show(a, *args, **kwargs):
    a = sorted(a, key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[1]))
    points = np.array(a)[:, :2]
    ax = kwargs.pop('ax', plt.gca())
    xmax, ymax = kwargs.pop('rects', [None, None])
    ax.plot(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], *args, **kwargs)
    if xmax:
        for x, y in points:
            rect = mpatches.Rectangle((x, y), xmax-x, ymax-y, color="blue", alpha=0.1)
            ax.add_patch(rect)

tests = [
    [[4, 34, 1], [5, 87, 2], [2, 76, 9], [4, 56, 12], [9, 34, 76]],
    [[87, 26, 37], [50, 37, 23], [70, 97, 19], [86, 91, 55], [57, 55, 68],
     [25, 35, 64], [82, 79, 66], [1, 30, 75], [16, 14, 71], [32, 89, 6]],
    np.random.randint(100, size=(10, 3)).tolist(),
    np.random.randint(100, size=(50, 3)).tolist(),
    np.random.randint(100, size=(100, 3)).tolist()]

assert all([sorted(using_product(test)) == sorted(using_sort(test)) 
            for test in tests])

for test in tests:
    print('test: {}'.format(test))
    show(test, 'o', label='test')
    for func, s in [('using_product', 20), ('using_sort', 10)]:
        result = locals()[func](test)
        print('{}: {}'.format(func, result))
        xmax, ymax = np.array(test)[:, :2].max(axis=0)
        show(result, 'o--', label=func, markersize=s, alpha=0.5, rects=[xmax, ymax])
    print('-'*80)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: A solution using `pairwise` from [itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) instead of explicit indexing might be more idiomatic Python. Also, since lists are compared lexicographically, you can get away with `a[i][:2] > a[i + 1][:2]`.

Comment: oh! there seems little probelm! I use a new list  a= [[4, 34, 1], [5, 87, 2], [2, 76, 9], [4, 56, 12], [9, 34, 76]]  , i use your code. yiels result=[[2, 76, 9], [4, 34, 1], [4, 56, 12], [5, 87, 2]] . But the result i need is: [[2, 76, 9], [4, 34, 1], [9, 34, 76]]. ! seems your code only removes the last sub-list .

Comment: You are right there was a problem in my code. Above is my attempt to fix it. Note that if you really want *strict* inequalities, `a[i][0]>a[j][0] and a[i][1]>a[j][1]`, then given `a= [[4, 34, 1], [5, 87, 2], [2, 76, 9], [4, 56, 12], [9, 34, 76]]` I believe the answer has to be `[[2, 76, 9], [4, 56, 12], [4, 34, 1], [9, 34, 76]]`, since none of the other sublists can eliminate `[4, 56, 12]`. `remove_sorted` (above) can be made much simpler if the inequalities used `>=` instead of `>`, but of course, the result would change.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
a=[[4,94,1], [3,67,2], [2,76,9]]
b = a
c = []

for lista in a:
    condition = False
    for listb in b:
        if (lista[0] > listb[0] and lista[1] > listb[1]):
            condition = True
            break

    if not condition:
        c.append(lista)
```

c will then contain the list of lists you want.

EDIT: Changed boolean condition based on Sergei's comment.

Comment: That is c will contain the list with all the elements matching your criteria removed.

Comment: Using `is` for booleans is redundant, `not condition` is preferable to `condition is False` (and shorter).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Why is using not better than is False? And what do you mean using is for booleans is redundant? I'm usually too focused on making things work so it would be great if you could teach me why certain things are more efficient =).

Comment: Is it because the "is" keyword compares the location of things in memory?

Comment: By redundancy I mean that you usually need `is` to obtain a boolean, e.g. `thing is None`. Therefore, doesn't make much sense to use `is` if you already have a boolean. This recommendation is part of [PEP-8](http://pep8.org/).

Comment: Ah, yes that makes sense. Thanks =).